# Calculating Homology Groups of $S^1\times X$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Given that $H_n(X)$ is free abelian, I'm trying to find the homology groups of $Y=S^1\times X$ using the Mayer-Vietoris theorem.

My first attempt decomposed $Y$ as $A \cup B$ where $A=\{*\}\times X$ and $B = S^1 \setminus \{*\}\times X$. Then $B$ clearly homotopy equivalent to $A$ and the Mayer-Vietoris sequence gives that $H_n(Y)=H_n(X)\bigoplus H_n(X)$.

This is clearly false (the torus is one easy counterexample). I assume that where I went wrong in is assuming that $B$ was triangulable. Am I right?

What would be the right way to go about this? Apart from what I tried I see no other decompositions which would work! I must be missing something.

Comment: Start by reading the statement of Mayer-Vietoris you are using. The usual form requires that the interiors of $A$ and $B$ cover $Y$. This is not the case here.

Comment: Ah that's a subtlety I hadn't picked up on! So if I modify my $A$ slightly so $A=U\times X$ for some small open set $U$ in $S^1$ then I should be able to use Mayer-Vietoris, right? In that case then $A\cap B=S^1$ and it's starting to look more correct! Thanks.

Comment: No, $A \cap B$ is homeomorphic to $((-1,0) \cup (0,1)) \times X$, and is homotopy equivalent to the disjoint union of two copies of $X$.

Comment: To make all this explicit, try looking at the case when $X$ is just a point.

Comment: Ah yes of course. That makes more sense. Can't see immediately that Mayer-Vietoris is now going to be useful though...

Comment: Is it required to use Mayer-Vietoris? If you have covered the Kunneth formula, this should come out pretty easily

Comment: I've read about the Kunneth formula and can see that it would be much easier using that, but the problem I'm trying to do explicitly states that I should use Mayer-Vietoris!

Comment: Think about how you'd go about using Mayer-Vietoris to compute homology of $S^1$ -- what open sets $U, V$ you'd use. Then use $U \times X$ and $V \times X$.

Comment: Surely I'd just use any two overlapping $U$ and $V$ with interiors covering $S^1$? Then both of these would be contractible, and the Mayer-Vietoris sequence tells us nothing... Could you give me a bigger hint?

Comment: @hgbreton: M-V does not tell you nothing there. Write it out and see.

Comment: Write $Y=S^1\times X$
Okay so we have exact sequence
$\dots\rightarrow H_n(Y)\rightarrow H_n(X) \bigoplus H_n(X)\rightarrow H_n(X) \bigoplus H_n(X) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(Y)\rightarrow \dots$

This doesn't seem very useful to me...

Comment: The real question is: what are the maps?

Comment: Writing from left to right the maps are $\delta_*, \alpha_*, \beta_*$. I presume that I'm meant to say something about $\alpha_*$ in particular right? Am I correct in thinking that it is the zero map for $n\geq 1$? And the identity map for $n=0$?

Comment: @hgbreton: First of all, I think you have the signature wrong: Given $X=A\cup B$, all of the "geometric" maps -- which are the degree-preserving ones -- are induced by inclusions.  That is, you should have $H_n(A\cap B) \rightarrow H_n(A) \oplus H_n(B) \rightarrow H_n(X)$.  There are two possible conventions for these maps: writing $i_U^V$ for the inclusion of $U$ into $V$, you can either take the first map to be $((i_{A\cap B}^A)_*,(i_{A\cap B}^B)_*)$ and the second map to be $\pm ((i_A^X)_* - (i_B^X)_*)$, or...

Comment: you can take the first map to be $(\pm (i_{A\cap B}^A)_*,\mp (i_{A\cap B}^B)_*)$ and the second map to be $\pm ((i_A^X)_* + (i_B^X)_*)$.  I think.  Check your book to see what conventions are chosen there.

Comment: I was working with the first convention. Is what I said wrong then? I don't really know how to work out $((i^A_{A∩B})_∗,(i^B_{A∩B})_∗)$ in this context. Could you point me in the right direction? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @hgbreton: The map to study is $H_n((U\cap V) \times X)$ $ \cong H_n((U\cap V)_1\times X)\oplus H_n((U\cap V)_2 \times X)$ $ \cong H_n(X) \oplus H_n(X) $ $\rightarrow H_n(U \times X) \oplus H_n(V\times X)$ $\cong H_n(X) \oplus H_n(X)$.  (The subscripts denote the two contractible components.)  With this convention, the map is $(\alpha,\beta) \mapsto (\alpha + \beta,\alpha + \beta)$.  Given that you know $H_*(X)$ is free abelian, you can determine the kernel and cokernel, and hence $H_*(X \times S^1)$ (there will be no extension problems, as you can (and must) show).

Comment: Thanks - I see more how to do it now. Just one final question - what is your reasoning for showing that the map is $(\alpha,\beta)\rightarrow(\alpha+\beta ,\alpha+\beta)$? I don't really see why that is true.

Comment: @hgbreton: This is simply because you chose the first convention!  Then, for any contractible space $C$, the map $H_n(C \times X) \rightarrow H_n(X)$ is an isomorphism.  I'm using this to explicitly identify all the copies of $H_n(X)$ running around (i.e. taking $C \in \{(U\cap V)_1,(U\cap V)_2,U,V\}$).

Comment: Thanks - I understand it now!

Comment: @EdwardHughes Would you like to share your understanding of this problem with others, by posting a solution? As is, the question is listed as Unanswered, which is why I came across it.

Answer (score 1):

Your choice of $A, B$ does not satisfy the standard prerequisite (the interiors of $A, B$ have to cover $S^1 \times X$) for applying the Mayer-Vietoris sequence. There are also other variants of M-V, but certainly no variant working for $A \cap B = \emptyset$ unless both $A, B$ are open.

See [Homology groups of $X \times S^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4853766) how to do it properly.

*Remark.*

I intended to close your question as a duplicate, but I think this would not answer where you went wrong.